# How to automate conversion of 3D DWG or DXF to STEP

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

want to make it easy for my make an automatic conversion (using a CLI or API) of 3D models (DWG/DXF) into STEP files.

I have tried to read the documentation for Autodesk Forge to see if that could help me, but have a hard time to understand if it can.

Can I do this with Autodesk Forge?
Is there some other way to do it?
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

How about to start with a working sample? Below is a few good starting points for your requirements:

- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bucket.manager-csharp-sample.tool
- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-curl
- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs

And feel free to find more samples here:

- https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge
- https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog
- https://autodesk-forge-showroom.herokuapp.com

Basically to either build scripts or app in any language of your choice (the beauty of RESTful API being language neutral) to automate the workflow for you requirements can be broken down to:

> Persist model files to/Read from your persistence (entirely your domain) -> Persist the model to Forge OSS (doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/app-managed-bucket)] > Call the conversion job(doc [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/) and [supported formats](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/) -> Poll for job status and retrieve a manifest for download ([here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/))-> Dowbload and persist the output (derivatives) ([here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/))

Edit:
To convert DWG to STP (which is not yet supported by the Translation Service), use the Design Automaion for AutoCAD service to automate the process. Basically you will need to create a .NET plug-in to export DWG to STP, submit the module as an AppPackage and invoke the automation activity via the service endpoints. See [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/developers_guide/overview/) for details.

Comment: You mention the supported formats (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/). 

By looking at it, converting from DWG/DXF to STP is *not* possible. If that is the case, I guess no working sample in the world would help me much...

Comment: Can work this around by converting to a supported format first and then to STP

Comment: According to the table of supported conversions DWG/DXF can only be converted to SVF which is the autodesk viewer format. And according to the table, it is not possible to convert SVF to anything. So please explain to me which chain of conversions I should do. To me, it seems like autodesk forge is mostly about making it possible to show "any" kind of file in the autodesk viewer.

Comment: in that case you can try the Design Automation service to export the drawings to STP. See details [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/developers_guide/overview/)

Comment: I can not find any information on the available output formats supported by the Design Automation API. Do you know where to find it?